# Getting Virtual path of a web page from a web service in c#

Tags: c#

I want to get virtual path of a web page from a web service. Is there any way to do this?.
suppose i have an aspx page like aa, i want to get full path as a url for that page from my web service.

Regards,
Harsh Suman

Answer (score 1):

What type of web-service? asmx? or wcf (svc)?

With asmx, you can use `HttpContext.Current` to get the current ASP.NET request, so you can get pretty-much anything you can get with ASP.NET; try looking at the `.Request` property of `HttpContext.Current`.

With wcf, this is not recommended - but it can be made to work if you enable ASP.NET compatibility.

Comment: Why is this not recommended with WCF?

Comment: @Lawrence - because the *default* is that WCF happens completely outside the ASP.NET pipeline, so there is no Current etc. You can enable compatibility mode, but...

Comment: For WCF services how about `WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.RequestUri` (and the other properties of `UriTemplateMatch`)? That seems to have the requested information and not require ASP.NET compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the post above. You can use the HttpContext.Current.Request object to get at  virtual path and request URL.

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
```

or if you want the full URL:

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.OriginalString;
```